# Foreach loop only looping once?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm having trouble with my foreach loop opening multiple files.

My foreach loop is only running once for the first item number. The foreach loop runs then goes to the "api.php" page but then stops and doesn't go back to the foreach loop to get the next item number. How do I tell it to go through all of item numbers in my database?

Would I use cURL somehow?

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
$itemnumber = array("".$result['item_number']."");

foreach ($itemnumber as $item_number) {

echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"api.php\" name=\"ChangeSubmit\" id=\"ChangeSubmit\">";
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"item_number\" value=\"{$item_number}\" />";

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function myfunc () {
var frm = document.getElementById(\"ChangeSubmit\");
frm.submit();
}
window.onload = myfunc;
</script></form>";



}
```

Comment: You are aware that the array has only one item?

Comment: This script will leave you very, very unhappy once you get this problem fixed...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Any chance the script name is wife.php?

Comment: also the content of the foreach loop seems like something i wouldn't want more than once. you will have many myfunc in your output and many html elements with the same id

Comment: Why would this script leave me unhappy?

Answer (score 3):

The `foreach` looks okay, but if you want to let it iterate over multiple numbers, you need to provide multiple. Right now you provide one number only.

Comment: 'item_number' is the name of a field in my database so it is pulling more than one number. When I echo this out I get all of the item numbers in my database but when 'item number' is sent to 'amazon.php' it doesn't come back to get the next item number.

Comment: @myladeybugg: just because your DB call returns `1,2,3,4` doesn't mean PHP is going to see those as individual IDs. It's going to see a SINGLE string.

Comment: It looks to me like its being individualized, by the way it comes out through the echo. Each one of the item numbers <br>'s and has an input field. Shows me that the echo is being ran multiple times---maybe I'm thinking of it wrong? Also, the first item number is being successfully searched and added into the DB, otherwise I think with all the numbers stuck together maybe it would error out on the API search? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You actually have only one item in your array. SO it is looping only once.

Your code `$itemnumber = array("".$result['item_number']."");` will translate to

```
 $itemnumber = array($result['item_number']);
```

Because, the double double-quotes you provided have no significance in the code too. SO, at last the array will have only one item.

Comment: Whoops, I should have been more specific. The $result['item_number'] is being pulled from the database. Its pulling out all the item numbers stored and assigning them to that var. In the echo, it has all the individual item numbers being echoed, in what seems like a proper loop. Since, it looks like there is only one item number per echo, and an input field attached to it. Or am I missing it?? Thanks!